# what means MaxInUse for bfc_allocator in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I encountered an OOM error while running tensorflow code. I am confused about these indicators, such as Limit, InUse, MaxInUse, NumAllocs, MaxAllocSize. Can anyone help explain it?thanks!

```
2021-12-01 21:08:29.733639: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:641] 14 Chunks of size 221773824 totalling 2.89GiB
2021-12-01 21:08:29.733644: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:641] 4 Chunks of size 325730304 totalling 1.21GiB
2021-12-01 21:08:29.733649: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:641] 1 Chunks of size 325844992 totalling 310.75MiB
2021-12-01 21:08:29.733654: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:641] 2 Chunks of size 591396864 totalling 1.10GiB
2021-12-01 21:08:29.733658: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:645] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 9.26GiB
2021-12-01 21:08:29.733667: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:647] Stats: 
Limit:                 10255859712
InUse:                  9942288128
MaxInUse:               9942288128
NumAllocs:                    8892
MaxAllocSize:            591396864

2021-12-01 21:08:29.733905: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:271] *********************************************************_******************************************
2021-12-01 21:08:29.733938: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at cwise_ops_common.cc:70 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[4096,141,96] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```